# What does this error when using django mean?

Tags: python, django

What does this error mean?

```
File "C:\Users\Admin\Projects\trydjango\musicyltd\restaurants\views.py", line 25, in contact
    return render(request, "contact.html", context)
  File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\shortcuts.py", line 36, in render
    content = loader.render_to_string(template_name, context, request, using=using)
  File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\template\loader.py", line 62, in render_to_string
    return template.render(context, request)
  File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\template\backends\django.py", line 63, in render
    reraise(exc, self.backend)
  File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\template\backends\django.py", line 84, in reraise
    raise new from exc
django.template.exceptions.TemplateDoesNotExist: base.html
[25/Apr/2018 13:54:27] "GET /contact/ HTTP/1.1" 500 120949
```

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow.com. Please take some time to read the [help pages](https://stackoverflow.com/help), especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). Also please [take the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read about [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) good questions. Lastly please learn how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: What do you find so difficult to understand in the sentence "template 'base.html' does not exist" ?

Answer (score 2):

Your `contact.html` loads a `base.html` but the loader can't find it. This is caused by a `{% extends %}` that points to a wrong path or a not existing template.